# OleDbException was unhandled : SQL: Column 'Q0P2' is not found [update dbf free tables from oledataadapter]

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, dbf, oledbdataadapter

Still my problem has not been solved and hence I come back with different issue for update dbf file [free table -vfp] from C# OleDbDataAdapter.

```
string MyConStr = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1; Data Source='C:\\Temp'; Persist Security Info=False";

VFPDAp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
VFPDAp.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand();
VFPDAp.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand();

VFPDAp.InsertCommand.CommandText = "insert into my_table1 (my_time,reminder) values(?, ?, ?)";
VFPDAp.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "update my_table1 set my_time=?, reminder=? where sl_no=? ";

VFPDAp.InsertCommand.Connection = OleCon1;
VFPDAp.UpdateCommand.Connection = OleCon1; 

OleDbParameter Par1 = new OleDbParameter("my_time", -1);
Par1.DbType = DbType.String;
Par1.SourceColumn = "my_time";
Par1.ParameterName = "my_time";

OleDbParameter Par2 = new OleDbParameter("reminder", -1);
Par2.DbType = DbType.String;
Par2.SourceColumn = "reminder";
Par2.ParameterName = "reminder";

OleDbParameter Par3 = new OleDbParameter("my_time", -1);
Par3.DbType = DbType.String;
Par3.SourceColumn = "my_time";
Par3.ParameterName = "my_time";

OleDbParameter Par4 = new OleDbParameter("reminder", -1);
Par4.DbType = DbType.String;
Par4.SourceColumn = "reminder";
Par4.ParameterName = "reminder";

VFPDAp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(Par1);
VFPDAp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(Par2);
VFPDAp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(Par3);
VFPDAp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(Par4);

OleCon1.ConnectionString = MyConStr;
OleCon1.Open();
VFPDAp.Update(VfpTbl);
OleCon1.Close();
```

Thanks For The Helps

Comment: did you catch the exception and pinned down the exact statement causing error

Comment: Hi, Codelgnoto... thanks...VFPDAp.Update(VfpTbl);

Comment: insert into my_diary (my_time,reminder) values(?, ?) update my_diary set my_time=? where reminder=?   Its solves my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Insert statement has 3 "?" but only 2 parms

```
insert into my_table1 (my_time,reminder) values(?, ?, ?)
(should it be 3 columns inserted or 2...)

update my_table1 set my_time=?, reminder=? where sl_no=?
```

Each "?" needs its own parameter, so you need a total of 5 (or 6 via insert)